# How to Define String Writer Length

Tags: c#

I have a Writline C# code. However each query will bring back a diffrent length (to be populated in a excel database). I can get the length, but I am unsure how to define the n value in the Writline query below (where n will be diffrent each time, I can get the length, but how to define the writeline). Many thanks.

```
sw.WriteLine(string.Format("\"{0}\",\"{1}\",\"{2}\",\"{3}\......n)
```

Comment: `String.Join` seems more appropriate. Either that or a loop over `sw.Write` (with a `WriteLine` only at the end).

Comment: *excel database* - please avoid saying this phrase ever again. If you get into the habit of it it might slip out somewhere vital, like an interview

Answer (score 0):

> I can get the length

Then you can make a format string:

```
var fmt = string.Concat(Enumerable.Range(0, theLength).Select(i => "{" + i + "}"));
```

If `theLength` is 3, your `fmt` string ends up as "{0}{1}{2}"

---

Other helpful factoid. The compiler takes this:

```
string.Format("....", a, b, c, ...);
```

And turns it into something like this:

```
var an_array = new object[]{ a, b, c, ... };
string.Format("...", an_array);
```

So if you already have an array there's nothing stopping you supplying it:

```
string.Format(fmt, your_array);
```

Methods that take a `params` arg are internally rewritten to take the N number of params as an array; you're always allowed to shortcut that and provide the array

Comment: Building this particular format string dynamically is pointless, since no actual format specifiers are included, so that it's the same thing as concatenating the string representations of the inputs -- so just use `String.Concat` directly on those. Even in more general scenarios, building a composite format string this way would be less efficient and more fragile than simply concatenating individually formatted elements (optionally through `StringBuilder`).

Comment: @Caius Jard thanks this did the trick, thank you